# whats is LibUsbDotNet 2.2.8 Analog for using in Mac OS.

Tags: c#, windows, vb.net, macos, usb

There is a **libusbdotnet.dll** that can be used to interface devices in vb.net referencing that dll written in C#.

What can it be done if I am using [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono_on_MacOS_X) to use vb.net in MAC?

Is there anything available, or maybe the solution is to code in C# all the stuff as **libusbdotnet is in C#**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter what language libusbdotnet is written in, as long as you include the DLL in your Mono VB.NET project you can use it.

Comment: but does it matter if I am on MAC OS?

Comment: Have you tried it? A quick Google search would indicate that LibUsbDotNet does in fact work with Mono (as long as you have the appropriate native libraries installed on the machine). Here's one of the results: http://libusb.6.n5.nabble.com/DllNotFoundException-Mono-td4341867.html